# Is it necessary join Bootstrap with Material angular to design?

Tags: angular-material, bootstrap-4

I need develop SPA with angular and angular material, but I need this SPA to be responsive, but I do not know if I need to use the bootstrap libraries or if it is possible to do everything with material, it confuses me with the issue of using those md-12 with bootrstrap, my idea is not to use bootstrap and do everything with material.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Material doesn't deal with screen responsiveness. If you want to stay within the Angular family, use [angular/flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout)

Comment: What is the difference between flex-layout with bootstrap? or simply flex-layout it's from angular family?

Comment: Read here about https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/API-Documentation. It solely deals with screen responsiveness, no css or UI component provided, much more friendlier to use with Angular 2. Basically material+flex-layout will be equivalent as a library to bootstrap.